# jQuery and 403 error and cors issue about my spring rest service40

Tags: javascript, java, spring, cors

> Spring API is running smoothly.I get this error message when I
>   try to access the data by the client. Even though I added Cors, the
>   problem did not improve. Below I will share my rest controller and
>   ajax methods.
>
> ERROR:

[image]

Here is my spring rest api url:

http://localhost:8080/getAllPLayers

also i already added the CrossOrigin anotation to my controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8000/")
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    FootballService footballService;

    //**PLAYER**
    @GetMapping(value="/getAllPLayers")
    public List<Player> getAllPlayers(){
        return footballService.getPlayerList();
    }
}
```

Dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

here is the ajax call function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#getAllPlayers").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        ajaxGet();
    });

    function ajaxGet(){
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url :  "http://localhost:8080/getAllPLayers/",

            success: function(result){
                /*****/
                alert("success!");
                $('#getResultDiv ul').empty();
                var playerList = "<table border='1'>";
                playerList += "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>Age</td></tr>";

                $.each(result, function(i, player){
                    playerList +="<tr>";
                    playerList +="<td>"+player.playerName +"</td>";
                    playerList +="<td>"+player.playerSurname+"</td>";
                    playerList +="<td>"+player.playerAge+"</td>";
                    playerList +="</tr>";
                });
                playerList +="</table>";
                $('#getResultDiv').append(playerList)
                console.log("Success: ", result);
        },
            error : function(e) {
                $("#getResultDiv").html("<strong>Error</strong>");
                console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            }
        }); 
    }
})
```

HTML part

```
 <!-- *** Players *** --> 

    <h3 style="color: darkolivegreen" ><strong>Player System</strong></h3>
  <div class="col-sm-7" style="margin:20px 0px 20px 0px">
      <button id="getAllPlayers">Get all players</button>
      <div id="getResultDiv" style="padding:20px 10px 20px 50px">
            <ul class="list-group">
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


 <!-- *** -->
```

I don't know where I made a mistake.

Comment: Have you added spring security dependencies ? If you are not using it, may be remove it and try.

Comment: i added dependencies and html part .

Comment: The server is sending back a 403 error response to the GET request. The cause of the 403 error has nothing to do with your CORS configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add filter class for **CORS** issue as below

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {


public SimpleCORSFilter() {
    log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

}
```

Comment: i have only one controller, I added the beginning of my controller, shared codes one by one at the top. I've tried cors with the correct url. 8000 port has javascript application, 8080 port is my own spring rest api.

Comment: updates the answer

Comment: what is the correct import of the Filter interface? and where the "log" came from

Comment: log is not needed here, remove that from import, 
import filter from `javax.servlet.Filter`

Comment: i removed but how can i import Filter clearly?

Comment: you can update the below line  with the URL 
`response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));`

Comment: Which one? the  '@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8000/")'  line?

Comment: replace `request.getHeader("Origin")` with 'localhost....'